# Running multiple functions javascript

Tags: php, javascript, function

I currently have a table that is being populated by a MySQL table, in turn i want to take the data from these cells and use them to create a simulated real time update, i have it working however due to having multiple rows im using for loops in the javascript functions and i believe this is causing the other functions not to run and i cannot figure out a way round it.

Javascript Code:

```
var seconds = 5;
var divid = "status";
var url = "boo.php";
var timeout;

function refreshdiv(){

// The XMLHttpRequest object

var xmlHttp;
try{
xmlHttp=new XMLHttpRequest(); // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
}
catch (e){
try{
xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); // Internet Explorer
}
catch (e){
try{
xmlHttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
catch (e){
alert("Your browser does not support AJAX.");
return false;
}
}
}

// Timestamp for preventing IE caching the GET request

fetch_unix_timestamp = function()
{
return parseInt(new Date().getTime().toString().substring(0, 10))
}

var timestamp = fetch_unix_timestamp();
var nocacheurl = url+"?t="+timestamp;

// The code...

xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
if(xmlHttp.readyState==4){
document.getElementById(divid).innerHTML=xmlHttp.responseText;
setTimeout('refreshdiv()',seconds*1000);
}
}
xmlHttp.open("GET",nocacheurl,true);
xmlHttp.send(null);
}

// Start the refreshing process

var seconds;
window.onload = function startrefresh(){
setTimeout('refreshdiv()',seconds*1000);
}

function runningtime(int) {
if(int == 0) { //if there is data
console.log("int=0 so no data is present, int: " + int);

} else if(int == 1){
var isRunning = new Array();
isRunning[0] = " ";
for (var i=0; i < 3; i++) {
var bool = 'running' + i;
console.log("Running = " + bool);
running = document.getElementById(bool).innerHTML.substring(10,11);

console.log("running: " + running);

if(isRunning[i] == "1") {

var time = 'Time' + i;

a= document.getElementById(time).innerHTML;
console.log("a= " + a);

  hour=a.substring(0,2);
  min= a.substring(3,5);
  sec= a.substring(6,8);

  sec==sec++;

if (min<=9) { min="0"+min; }
if (sec<=9) { sec="0"+sec; }

time = (hour + ":" + min + ":" + sec + " ");

if (document.getElementById) { document.getElementById(time).innerHTML = time; }
else if (document.layers) {
 document.layers.theTime.document.write(time);
 document.layers.theTime.document.close(); }

} else {
//Do nothing
return;
}
}
timeout = setTimeout("runningtime(1)", 1000);
}
}

function experiencehour(exp) {
if(exp == 0) { //if there is dexphourtexphour
console.log("exp=0 so no data is present, exp: " + exp);

} else if(exp == 1){

var isRunning = new Array();
isRunning[0] = " ";
for (var i=0; i < 3; i++) {
var bool = 'running' + i;
console.log("Running = " + bool);
running = document.getElementById(bool).innerHTML.substring(10,11); //checks if bot running

console.log("running: " + running);

if(isRunning[i] == "1") {

var exph = 'Exph' + i;
var expg = 'Exp' + i;

exphour = document.getElementById(exph).innerHTML; //exphour
currexp = document.getElementById(exp).innerHTML; //current gained exp
exphour =parseInt(exphour);
currexp =parseInt(currexp);

console.log("currexp= " + currexp);
console.log("exphour= " + exphour);

expmin = exphour/60;
console.log("expmin= " + expmin);
expsec = Math.round(expmin/60);
console.log("expsec= " + expsec);

newtotalexp = currexp + expsec;
console.log("newtotalexp= " + newtotalexp);

if (document.getElementById) { document.getElementById(exp).innerHTML = newtotalexp; } //writing new exp
else if (document.lexphouryers) {
 document.lexphouryers.theTime.document.write(time);
 document.lexphouryers.theTime.document.close(); }

} else {
//Do nothing
return;
}
}
timeout = setTimeout("experiencehour(1)", 1000);
}
}

function variable1hour(var1) {
if(var1 == 0) { //if there is dvar1hourtvar1hour
console.log("var1=0 so no data is present, var1: " + var1);

} else if(var1 == 1){

var isRunning = new Array();
isRunning[0] = " ";
for (var i=0; i < 3; i++) {
var bool = 'running' + i;
console.log("Running = " + bool);
isRunning[i] = document.getElementById(bool).innerHTML.substring(10,11); //checks if bot running
console.log("isRunning = " + isRunning[i]);



if(isRunning[i] == "1") {

var varh = 'Varh' + i;
var varg = 'Var' + i;

console.log("Varh = " + varh);
console.log("Var = " + varg);

var1hour = document.getElementById(varh).innerHTML; //var1hour
currvar1 = document.getElementById(varg).innerHTML; //current gained var1
var1hour =parseInt(var1hour);
currvar1 =parseInt(currvar1);

console.log("currvar1= " + currvar1);
console.log("var1hour= " + var1hour);

var1min = var1hour/60;
console.log("var1min= " + var1min);
var1sec = Math.round(var1min/60);
console.log("var1sec= " + var1sec);

newtotalvar = currvar1 + var1sec;
console.log("newtotalvar= " + newtotalvar);

if (document.getElementById) { document.getElementById(varg).innerHTML = newtotalvar; } //writing new var1
else if (document.lvar1houryers) {
 document.lvar1houryers.theTime.document.write(time);
 document.lvar1houryers.theTime.document.close(); 
 }

} else {
//Do nothing
return;
}
}
 timeout = setTimeout("variable1hour(1)", 1000);
}
}

function stopScript() {
console.log("Stopping script");
clearTimeout(timeout);
}

function startScript(i) {
variable1hour(i);
experiencehour(i);
runningtime(i);
}
```

Any ideas on how i can get around this so i can get all 3 functions running simultaneously.

I have checked console and im not getting any errors that would stop them from running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't have simultaneously in JS.  But you can **simulate** simultaneous a bit in JS.

Take a look at underscore's `defer` method.

http://underscorejs.org/#defer

It'd work like this:

- Take the loop body and wrap it up in a function
- Each iteration through the for loop, make a call to the function using defer

That's basically it.  Doing that will allow other functions to "interrupt" any given process (function) and thus "share" the execution thread.

A standard JS implementation w/out defer.  I'm trying to simulate the closer of defer.  The key takeaway here is that, while the calls still execute in the order that they were queued, all get "started" before any one of them completes.  In the case of AJAX async requests, the async response should be able to inject itself between any two loop iterations.  You can also set data processing by using slight delays

http://jsfiddle.net/t2z9A/

```
for(var i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
{
    (function(index)
     {
         document.getElementById('id' + index).innerHTML = 'started...';

         setTimeout(function()
         {
             // kill some time
             var str = '';
             for(var j = 0; j != 10000000; ++j)
                 str = str + ' ';

             document.getElementById('id' + index).innerHTML = 'Function: 1.  Index: ' + index + ' - ' + new Date().getTime();
         }, index);
     })(i);
}

for(var i = 5; i != 10; ++i)
{
    (function(index)
     {
         document.getElementById('id' + index).innerHTML = 'started...';

         setTimeout(function()
         {
             // kill some time
             var str = '';
             for(var j = 0; j != 1000000; ++j)
                 str = str + ' ';

             document.getElementById('id' + index).innerHTML = 'Function: 2.  Index: ' + index+ ' - ' + new Date().getTime();
         }, 1);
     })(i);
}
```

Comment: A small note: the more you "defer" and splice up your loop body into units, the more shared it'll be.  Each function will execute until it's done before letting another function execute.  So slice and dice as much as you see fit in order to get the type of execution sharing you want.

Comment: so idealy i would want to defer after each iteration of the for loops so it will update almost a row at a time then move on downwards?

Comment: Yes.  Something like: `for(var i = 0; i != 3; ++i) { _.defer(fn, i); }` where `fn` is the function with the body, and the only parameter you need for it to execute is `i`.  And giving your code a quick peek, it looks like that's all you'd need.  Give it a try! I edited my code with a standard JS implementation for comparison.  Simulating an "interruption" was tricky, but I wanted to show you how it'd queue up and not wait for an entire for loop (simulated function) to complete before moving on to the next one.  I hope this helps.

Comment: Been trying to get it to work for the past hour but still getting no luck, getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: _ is not defined " in console with the code:
    
for(var r = 0; r != 3; ++r) {
 _.defer(variable1hour(i), r);
}

Comment: Did you include the underscore library? _.defer is not standard.  If it's not showing up and you've included it, make sure you've included it BEFORE this script is executing, and make sure that the reference isn't 404'ing or some other error.